# Kill Ubuntu Gnome?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I have an ubuntu server which I installed ubuntu-dekstop upon.

Then i started the Gnome Desktop with "startx" command.

I wonder:

1. how do I kill Gnome so I can go back to only CLI?
2. how do i disable Gnome form starting when Ubuntu server starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 alternatives for the "kill gnome" part.

- Since Ubuntu disabled the ctrl+alt+backspace combination, all you have to do is [re-enable the combination](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-enabledisable-ctrlaltbackspace-in-ubuntu-9-10-karmic.html)
- Or you can use `alt+sysrq+K`, this `magic sysrq key` combination kills all X programs.

To prevent Gnome starting on the startup, use update-rc.d to remove gdm.

```
# update-rc.d gdm remove
```

Answer (score 1):

To get out of Gnome, click on the power-button-shaped icon (a circle with a vertical bar near the top) near the right of the top menu bar and select “Log Out”.

If you want to disable the graphical login manager, either uninstall the `gdm` package or arrange for the gdm service not to start by commenting out the `start (...)` paragraph in `/etc/init/gdm.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch back to a console using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd> keystroke where "F1" could be any number (often F1-F6) that represents the virtual consoles that are enabled on your system. You can use F7 or F9 to return to X depending on which one your system uses.

Beware of the magic sysrq. There are some dangerous key combinations such as immediate reboot.